# Plotly scatterplot using pandas groupby for traces

Tags: pandas, plotly

I run into this pattern quite often. I want my traces to be the results of a groupby operation.

```
data = dict(
    time = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
    satellite_ID = [3,24,9,3,24,9,3,24,9],
    satellite_type = ['gps','glonass','galileo']*3,
    snr = [28,34,26,27,35,25,28,36,24])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The x-axis is time, the y-axis is SNR, and each line+marker trace is a unique satellite ID. There should be 3 traces at time 1, 2, and 3 for each satellite. A nice addition would be to have each satellite_type be a different color and visible on mouse hover.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out from the documentation.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
data = dict(
    time = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
    satellite_ID = [3,24,9,3,24,9,3,24,9],
    satellite_type = ['gps','glonass','galileo']*3,
    snr = [28,34,26,27,35,25,28,36,24])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="snr", color='satellite_ID',
             hover_data=['satellite_type'] )

fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines")
```

"color" selects the traces, and additional hover data can be entered using the "hover_data' argument to px.line.